# How to compute loss of chained models with Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

For testing, I have split a model into two models and I want to compute the loss and apply the gradient to both models like it would be one.

Here are my two simple models:

```
model1 = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="relu", input_shape=(10,)),
])

model2 = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax", input_shape=(10,)),
])
```

And I run a forward pass through the two models, calculate the loss of the second model and apply the gradients:

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD()
loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

x = tf.random.normal((1, 10)) # Input of the 1st model
y = tf.random.normal((1, 10)) # Expected output of the 2nd model

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    pred1 = model1(x, training=True)
    pred2 = model2(pred1, training=True)
    loss_value2 = loss(y, pred2) # Compute the loss for the second model prediction

grads = tape.gradient(loss_value2, model2.trainable_variables)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model2.trainable_variables))
```

But how do I get the expected output of the first model wrt the second model to compute the loss and apply gradients on it?

EDIT:

The end goal of the testing is to have two models 1, that send their output to a single third model. And having each model 1 trained on two GPUs:

```
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    pred1_1 = model1_1(x, training=True)

with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
    pred1_2 = model1_2(x, training=True)

pred1 = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([pred1_1, pred1_2])

with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    pred2 = model2(pred1, training=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Begoodpy,
I suggest you combine the 2 models into a single one and train it as you would usually do.

```
supermodel = keras.Sequential(
    [
      model1(),
      model2(),
    ]
```

If you need more control over the models, try this:

```
all_vars = model1.trainable_variables + model2.trainable_variables

grads = tape.gradient(loss_value2, all_vars)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, all_vars))
```

Comment: Thanks but I intend to send each model to one GPU each, so I can't have them in one model

Comment: With 2 GPUs why not combine my answer with the other one from Alexandre Catalano? The TF will do the splitting across GPUs for you.

Comment: Because those are workarounds and doesn't solve my problem. I have constraints, like the models size that can't fit into one GPU, and neither combining the models, nor distributed strategy will help.

Comment: you can join 2 lists of vars and pass it to the backprop functions. I added an example above.

Comment: That looks awesome! Isn't the same as calling twice `tape.gradient(loss_value2, model1.trainable_variables)` and `tape.gradient(loss_value2, model2.trainable_variables)`?

Comment: Glad it helped. And thanks for fixing my typos!
Calling twice like in your example will likely not work, because `loss_value2` is not directly linked with `model1`. Besides, tape can only be used once and your example will cause error `RuntimeError: GradientTape.gradient can only be called once on non-persistent tapes.`
If satisfied with the answer - pls mark it as accepted and upvote.